# Running Macros without opening excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I wonder how would you assign VBA codes written on Excel VBA to a sort of procedure/programme or maybe dos related filepath, which you can directly without opening excel. In other word, i want to have a desktop icon i can stir up a vba code i assigned to.

Comment: You can't run a Excel VBA Macro `without` opening the File that contains the macro. If you want you can launch the excel application in hidden mode and then run the macro after opening the file in hidden mode from a VBS file.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to try VB.Net.  I found the learning curve from VBA to **simple** VB.Net pain free.  The Express version is free and the limitations are unlikely to be a concern if you just want to produce desktop utilities.

Comment: @Tony: This would not always be possible. For instance, in my department we develop Excel tools for internal clients but we do not have access to VS licenses.

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur. If you want to develop Excel addins in VB.Net then I agree you need a non-free version because the ability to create addins is not included in the free version. But I read serhat's question as meaning he just wants VBA without Excel.  You licence VB.Net Express by registering.  The Net Runtime is standard within Windows so you can develop and distribute stand-alone programs internally and externally.

Comment: Post your code so we help with the [tag:vbs] that Sid suggested

Comment: For many tasks Excel is very slow, it would be great to find other program to run macros (Excel and Word) from the command line.

Comment: How about using VBS

Answer (score 8):

You can do it easily.

Add the following content in a VBS file (e.g. example.vbs). This is only a text file that you can write using Notepad:

```
'Code should be placed in a .vbs file
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\path\to\my\excel\file\myExcelMacroFile.xlsm'!MyModule.MyFunctionName"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Then you can double clic on the VBS file to execute it.

Source: http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/

Comment: Using above line how to pass parameters to the function? Lets MyFunctionName has input parameter as String

Comment: @Nitin: Apparently, you need to add the parameters after the function name, with comma as a separator, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876338/pass-argument-from-vbs-to-vba (I didn't test that)

Comment: how is this the top answer? This opens excel and executes the file, not what the question was..

Answer (score 3):

If the VBA in the Excel macro doesn't reference Excel objects, you can just copy the code into a text file and change the extension to .VBS. However, VB script doesn't like it when you use types, just delete the "AS something" from your Dim statement.

I do this often to get the benefit of Intellisense, which I wouldn't have using Notepad.

If my assumption is correct, then you probably want to change your tags to VB Scripting instead of Excel to get appropriate help.

Answer (score 2):

*If* I understand that right, you can simply write VBS code in a text file and rename it to .vbs
(make sure file endings are visible in Windows). On doubleclick the file is executed by the Windows Scripting Host. VBS lacks some functionality of VBA but you can do a lot with CreateObject/GetObject.

Comment: I was quite excited with such a shortcut cogent solution but it gives error

Answer (score 0):

Though the learning curve may be a bit steep, but you could consider using AutoHotKey. This allows you to create your own scripts and if so desired turn them into (rather large) .exe files. AutoHotKey is free!

Answer (score 0):

write a cmd or ps1 that opens an excel and in that excel's startup run your macro... and then  when finished close it.

this can be a solution but you are probably doing something which is unnecessary in correct planned environments.