# Pass Argument from VBS to VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript, argument-passing

I try to call a VBA subroutine from VBS with passing a string variable from VBS to VBA, but can't find the appropiate syntax:

```
'VBS:
'------------------------
Option Explicit

Set ArgObj = WScript.Arguments 
Dim strPath

mystr = ArgObj(0) '?

'Creating shell object 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Creating File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Getting the Folder Object
Set ObjFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(WshShell.CurrentDirectory)

'Getting the list of Files
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Creat a Word application object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = True
wdApp.Visible = True

'Running macro on each wdS-File
Counter = 0
For Each objFile in objFiles
  If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "DOC" Then
    set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ObjFolder & "\" & ObjFile.Name, 0, False) 
    wdApp.Run "'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Anwendungsdaten\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\MyVBA.dot'!Test_VBA_with_VBS_Args" (mystr) 'how to pass Argument???
    Counter = Counter + 1
  End if
Next

MsgBox "Macro was applied to " & Counter & " wd-Files from current directory!"

wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing



'------------------------
'VBA:
'------------------------
Sub Test_VBA_with_VBS_Args()

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
    Dim filename As String
    Dim mystr As String

    'mystr = how to recognize VBS-Argument ???

    filename = ActiveDocument.name
    MsgBox "..The file: " & filename & " was opened and the VBS-Argument: " & mystr & "recognized!" 

    wdDoc.Close

End Sub
'------------------------
```

Comment: comma separated?  oXL.Run "MyBook.xls!MyModule.MyMacro", var1, var2

Comment: ok, tried it with VBS: `var1 = ArgObj(0)` and `wdApp.Run "'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\kcichini\Anwendungsdaten\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\MyVBA.dot'!Test_VBA_with_VBS_Args", var1`, and in VBA: `mystr = var1` without success

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify parameters in your VBA `Sub` and use them as you would do if using it from VBA normally.

For example, I tried the following VBScript

```
dim wd: set wd = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
wd.Visible = true
wd.run "test", "an argument"
```

and the VBA

```
Sub Test(t As String)
    MsgBox t
End Sub
```

which worked successfully, generating a message box.

Comment: darn, it is really easy as that - @ocp, many thanks for the concise example!

Answer (score 12):

Addendum to @user69820 answer, if arguments are VBScript variables, they need to be cast as appropriate type before calling the subroutine:

This does not work:

```
dim argumentVariable
argumentVariable = "an argument"
wd.run "test", argumentVariable
```

This does:

```
dim argumentVariable
argumentVariable = "an argument"
wd.run "test", CStr(argumentVariable)
```

Tested on Excel 2010, Win7SP1 x64

Comment: Tested working on Excel 2016, Win 11