# Create and Run Macro in Excel 2010 using VBS file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have written a macro in excel that carries out the actions I need. However the issue comes in when I need the macro to be run in a new download. Obviously the macro will not be in this file. What I want to create is a file that will allow me to run this macro without having to copy and paste every time. After doing some research, I have found out this could be possible via a VBScript file. I have researched 2 methods and can't get either to work. They are, to open the file and try and execute the macro using a call function, and having the macro within the VBS File (I have made all the changes to the macro I know of to try and make it VBS) and the other method is to use the VBS file to create a new module and add the Macro code into the file. But I can't get anything to work. I can get the file to open and do little silly things like pop up messages, but that's all I have managed. Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks

(the question that is the same as mine, can someone explain what is happening with it, because I have looked at it and there is hardly any of it that I can follow)

Comment: Show the code, that does not work in the question.

Comment: Have you tried saving the macro in the XLSTART folder (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART) and running it through the VBA editor, or making a quickbutton on the ribbon to call the macro?  This assumes you're just working on the one computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Argument from VBS to VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876338/pass-argument-from-vbs-to-vba)

Comment: Hi Vityata,

Some of the code

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Macros\Test.xlsm")
  
Call ForecastReport()
Public Sub ForecastReport()


Dim lCol As Long
lCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

Comment: Cyril - Sorry that has gone well over my head - I am very very new to this. How would that work?

Comment: Hi Sean, that may be what I need, but all honest I have no idea what is going on in that code, and if its doing what I need. I have never used VBS or anything similar. This is the first macro I have written, and to  use it I am having to save a text file of it and then copy and paste into excel everytime I download a new report