# Retreiving/reading excel macro without opening excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I wrote an excel macro that seems to have broken, unfortunately when I try to edit the macro in the VBA editor, excel itself crashes spectacularly. This seems to happen whether I open the VBA Editor before or after loading the problematic excel file.

Does anyone know of a way of viewing the VBA code that I've written without using excel to get there? Alternatively, can anyone get to the VBA code in (this excel file)(Link Removed) without it crashing their excel?

Unlike "[Running Macros without opening excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759229/running-macros-without-opening-excel)" I don't need to be able to run the broken code without excel - just copy and paste it somewhere to fix it!

Comment: What about turning marcosecurity to disable macros from running and then extracting?

Comment: Copy your file, change extension to `zip`, then extract and use one of the tools in https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools to extract your code from `vbaProject.bin`! ;)

Comment: Tell me when you copy it so that I delete your code from the public ;)

Comment: @HanSoalone - unfortunately it still crashes when macro security is set to block all!!

Comment: @A.S.H - the code isn't private to be honest

Comment: Yeah I understood that from your question, but anyway. Does that hopefully solve your problem?

Comment: @R3uK - looks useful, if complicated to a non-python user - if I'm honest I've cheated and used Ash's copy :)

Comment: @A.S.H thanks it does solve everything. did you have any problems with the file or is it my copy of office?

Comment: I did not try to run the code, just could see it in the editor. I dont know if the problem was from a corrupted installation.

Comment: But I have to say that the first time I opened it "naively", yes it did crash my Excel program. I didnt mind that bc I am working on a "Test" machine somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fresh new excel file and open the VBA editor. Then I opened the one you provided, but I had put it in a non-secure folder. Excel prompted me the choice of opening it with macros disabled. I did, and I could see the code in the editor. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for the answer for the same question let me translate what the accepted answer means.

@R3uK provided the following link to Tools to extract VBA Macro source code from MS Office Documents: [decalage.info/vba_tools](https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools)

there are several tools there to extract code from Office documents, for most of them you have to first unzip the document itself. (newer Office documents are a collection of files in a zipped folder with a docx or xlsx extension.) you have to rename the document to filename.zip and copy the contents to a folder, then run the tool to get the macro source code.