# How to run excel macro using 'Get-Command -Module ImportExcel'

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a macro 'Refresh' in an excel.xlsm. What is the powershell command to run this without opening the excel? I want to open the excel,run the macro, save and close excel. I want to use ImportExcel module

Comment: Unless ImportExcel contains a VBA runtime you may be out of luck.

Comment: Could you run a VBS script from Powershell? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759229/running-macros-without-opening-excel

Comment: I am not sure about that, is there any other way to automate this apart from PowerShell?

Comment: @Absinthe - Thanks for the link, let me try this. I need to use this on server where excel is not installed. will this work?

Comment: Nope, you need to have it installed if you want to a) instantiate Excel and b) run macros

Comment: Here is an example on how to run macro in powershell. https://www.excell-en.com/blog/2018/8/20/powershell-run-macros-copy-files-do-cool-stuff-with-power

Comment: Thanks for link...it needs Excel to be installed on the server to use Excel.Application.i read somewhere that the module 'ImportExcel' can do this without installing the excel...but I don't know how to use this...